# Return a promise when foreach loop ends

Tags: javascript, typescript, foreach, firebase-realtime-database

I'm wanting to run a forEach loop then return (resolve?) a Promise so that my next function can run. I can correctly work out when the forEach is at the end but just dont know how to resolve the Promise.

Here is my code:

```
  addSubmissionsForms(submissionId: string, submittedFields:Array<any>): Promise<any> {
    const submissionPath:firebase.database.Reference = this.rootRef.child(`submissionsByID/${submissionId}/fields`);

    submittedFields.forEach(function(submittedField, i) {    
      let fieldId = submittedField.id;
      submissionPath.child(fieldId).update(submittedField);
      if(i == submittedFields.length - 1) {
        console.log('finished');

      }
    });
  }
```

The reason I want to return a Promise is because I want to wait until this function has run then run another function like this:

```
  this.submissionsProvider.addSubmissionsForms(submissionKey, this.submittedFields)
  .then(() => {
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  });
```

Comment: Why do you need a promise this does not seem to be async?

Comment: I want to wait until this function has run before running another function, Im also open to do this with callbacks too

Comment: yeah ok, but this function does not make anything that is asynchronous there is no need to wait. You can just call this function and then an other one.

Comment: Perfect - Indeed that does not need to be async, could you explain this more maybe in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you want to use promises you can do the following:

As a side note you can resovle any value e.g. `resolve('finished')`

```
addSubmissionsForms(submissionId: string, submittedFields:Array<any>): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const submissionPath:firebase.database.Reference = this.rootRef.child(`submissionsByID/${submissionId}/fields`);

        submittedFields.forEach(function(submittedField, i) {    
            let fieldId = submittedField.id;
            submissionPath.child(fieldId).update(submittedField);
            if (i == submittedFields.length - 1) {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    reject();
    });
}
```

If the function `addSubmissionsForms` does nothing async (like e.g. an ajax call or reading and writing into database) you don't really need promises because you just can execute functions one after another

```
addSubmissionsForms();
nextFunction();
```